# Gnome 3 public WebDAV share: how to access from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, gnome3, webdav

I'm trying to access the Public folder of my Gnome 3 system from Windows 10 computers in the same network. Gnome's File Sharing dialog says that the Public folder can be accessed at `dav://(hostname)/local`, meaning it's shared by WebDAV (right?), but Windows 10's file explorer mustn't accept `dav` connections, as when I type it into the location bar, it sends me to the Windows Store.

I know there's nothing wrong with my network, as I can access my Public folder from another Gnome 3 system at the `dav://` address.

Is there a way for `dav://` connections to be made from Windows 10, at least without any extra software? I've tried using `http(s)` instead of `dav`, but that doesn't work either. (I'm fine with using FTP sharing instead, but I'd to see if I can get this to work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows/ I just succeded with typing into the Windows Explorer address bar:

```
    \\<IP address>@<port number>\DavWWWRoot
```

With a working DNS `<server name>` will do instead of `<IP address>` I guess. The port number was found using `lsof -i` and looking for `apache2` ports in mode `LISTEN` on the WebDAV server.

This gave me the content of the public files of my Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch) machine, see https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/sharing-personal.html.en.

Answer (score 0):

gnome personal file sharing uses Multicast-DNS (mdns) /zeroconf / bonjour

https://commaster.net/content/how-resolve-multicast-dns-windows

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)