# Access Gnome''s webdav share from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, gnome, webdav, bonjour

I have the same problem as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247068/gnome-3-public-webdav-share-how-to-access-from-windows-10), but the listed answers on that question are not working for me, so it appears my situation may be different, or perhaps things have changed since then, so I figured I'd better ask a new question.

Essentially, I have sharing set up using the `gnome-user-share` package. It works between Linux computers, but I'd like to access it from Windows (Samba has given me grief, and also I'd just rather only have one file sharing service running on the machine rather than trying to manage 2 different ones).

In the question I've linked, it recommended sniffing the ports apache was listening on, and entering `\\<IP address>@<port number>\DavWWWRoot` in the windows address bar. I found apache running on 4 different ports, and none of them let me access the webdav share.

Another answer recommended installing Bonjour on the Windows machine. I have done so, but it seemed to change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

They're 4 different processes, not 4 different ports. Port numbers are at the last column.

The output of `lsof -i` in my computer is:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2   11514 abcd    4u  IPv6 311338      0t0  TCP *:45151 (LISTEN)
apache2   11515 abcd    4u  IPv6 311338      0t0  TCP *:45151 (LISTEN)
apache2   11516 abcd    4u  IPv6 311338      0t0  TCP *:45151 (LISTEN)
```